# Groundwater Basins

Tags: geospatial, environment

Is there a global database available for groundwater basins (Aquifers), similar to [gdbd](http://www.cger.nies.go.jp/db/gdbd/gdbd_index_e.html) for surface water?

Comment: Though it is not open data, there is a [global groundwater data set](http://www.bgr.bund.de/EN/Themen/Wasser/Produkte/produkte_node_en.html) maintained by the German Federal Institute for Geosciences and Natural Resources (BGR).

Comment: How do you define "groundwater"? Is that the same as an aquifer? Or are you referring to surface water?

Comment: I currently use WHYMAP: http://www.whymap.org/whymap/EN/Home/whymap_node.html

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe these are 100% on target, but they look pretty promising.

[Freshwater Ecoregions of the World (Data Basin Dataset)](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5c52b8a4dda94f598e8c5dbeb78ee57b))

[Food and Agriculture Organization's AQUASTAT database](http://www.fao.org/nr/water/aquastat/data/query/index.html?lang=en)

I can't post more than two links yet, but the USGS has a pretty solid database for all bodies of water in the United States, so make sure to check them out for US based data, at least.

Answer (score 5):

Global Water Forum lists a number of water related tools and resources, including datasets. A couple of these may be of use to you:
http://www.globalwaterforum.org/resources/data/

One in particular, the GGIS (Global Groundwater Information System):
http://www.un-igrac.org/global-groundwater-information-system-ggis

USGS Surfacewater Portal also has a number of tools and resources that you may find beneficial:
http://water.usgs.gov/osw/

NASA's GRACE Groundwater combines two major databases, again should also be very relevant here:
http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/hydrology/additional/science-focus/grace_groundwater.shtml